# Upload files to Google Drive API

Tags: spring, file-upload, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

someone knows how can I upload a file selected on client pc on my website and save it to client Drive?

The client clicks on input file button 
The client select the file at his pc
The client click upload button 
File is uploaded to user Drive

A guide or tutorial will be helpful, I tried docs, but there shows my user need to copy and paste an url to authenticate

I'm using Spring Mvc, Security, Servlet 3.1.

Can be to Dropbox too!

Comment: You may take a look at this [docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs) for Dropbox. It's quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

In order to interact with users Google or Dropbox drive you'll need to be authorized by the user, using OAuth2 in appropriate services, which is a task on it's own.

Spring has a whole Spring Social project, that provides needed integration infrastructure http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/, with some basic services in place.

You can take a look at https://github.com/vbfischer/spring-social-dropbox for Dropbox integration.